# Windows Media Foundation Degrades In Windows 8

Tags: c++, windows, video, h.264, ms-media-foundation

I have a workflow as follows:

1. Get raw YUV frame.
2. Pass it in to Windows Media Foundation to encode in to an H.264 frame.
3. Convert the output to an FFmpeg AVPacket.
4. Inject the packet with av_interleaved_write_frame to an output file mixed with other things.

On Windows 7, this worked great. On Windows 8, av_interleaved_write_frame broke. The reason for this is that Windows 8 introduced B-Frames to the output, which av_interleaved_write_frame just didn't like, no matter how I set the pts/dts.

I modified the encoder to use 0 B-Frames, which then gave me the output I wanted. But...

After about 10-15 seconds of encoded frames, the video degrades from nearly perfect to extremely blocky and a very low frame rate. I've tried changing most of the settings available to Windows 8 to modify the encoder, but nothing seems to help.

The only thing that did make an affect was changing the bitrate of the encoder. The more I increase the encoder bitrate, the longer the video goes before it starts to degrade.

Any ideas on what changed between Windows 7 and Windows 8 that may have caused this to happen?

**Encoder Setup Minus Success Checks (They All Succeed)**

```
IMFMediaType * mInputType = NULL;

MFCreateMediaType(&mOutputType);

mOutputType->SetGUID(MF_MT_MAJOR_TYPE, MFMediaType_Video);
mOutputType->SetGUID(MF_MT_SUBTYPE, MFVideoFormat_H264);
mOutputType->SetUINT32(MF_MT_AVG_BITRATE, 10000000);

MFSetAttributeSize(mOutputType, MF_MT_FRAME_SIZE, frameWidth, frameHeight);
MFSetAttributeSize(mOutputType, MF_MT_FRAME_RATE, 30, 1);
MFSetAttributeSize(mOutputType, MF_MT_FRAME_RATE_RANGE_MAX, 30, 1);
MFSetAttributeSize(mOutputType, MF_MT_FRAME_RATE_RANGE_MIN, 15, 1);

mOutputType->SetUINT32(MF_MT_INTERLACE_MODE, MFVideoInterlace_Progressive);
mOutputType->SetUINT32(MF_MT_ALL_SAMPLES_INDEPENDENT, 1);
mOutputType->SetUINT32(MF_MT_FIXED_SIZE_SAMPLES, 1);
mOutputType->SetUINT32(MF_MT_SAMPLE_SIZE, frameWidth * frameHeight * 2);
mOutputType->SetUINT32(MF_MT_MPEG2_PROFILE, eAVEncH264VProfile_Main);
mOutputType->SetUINT32(CODECAPI_AVEncCommonRateControlMode, eAVEncCommonRateControlMode_Quality);
mOutputType->SetUINT32(CODECAPI_AVEncCommonQuality, 80);
```

Encoding of the frame is basically:

1. MFCreateMemoryBuffer to store the incoming YUV data.
2. MFCreateSample.
3. Attach the buffer to the sample.
4. Set the sample time and duration.
5. ProcessInput
6. ProcessOutput with an the proper output size
7. On success, build an AVPacket with the sample's info

Comment: What if you just disable B frames on Windows 8 H.264 encoder?

Comment: The B-Frames are already disabled. This matched the way Windows 7 sends out the frames.